# Compare two array of array of objects

Tags: php, php-7

I want two know if two array of array of objects are identicals.

Here is how I did :

```
$differents1 = array_udiff(
    $array1,
    $array2,
    function ($cr1, $cr2) {
        return $cr1->getId() - $cr2->getId();
    }
);
$differents2 = array_udiff(
    $array2,
    $array1,
    function ($cr1, $cr2) {
        return $cr1->getId() - $cr2->getId();
    }
);
$isDifferent = empty($differents1) && empty($differents2);
```

It works but I wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: instead of two calls to udiff, I'd first compare lengths, and only if they are the same - run per element comparison

Comment: Whats wrong with `$array1 == $array2`?

Comment: Right ! My bad @FelippeDuarte

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions without a problem does not belong on SO. Questions about how to optimize or make code better belongs on code review.